# Getting Faces from vertex group using bmesh

Tags: python, bmesh

So I have a vertex group, and I want to hide the faces using the vertex from vertex group. So to do this, I need to either make a check if the face is in a vertex group, or I need to get the faces from the vertex.

The whole thing will be in edit mode but I do not want to do any actual selection in the scene during the process. So I can't just flush selection.

So is there any way I can get the faces so that i can use hideset in bmesh to hide the chosen faces?

the goal is to be able to hide faces base on vertex group.
The chosen face should have 4 vertices selected just like how we used to when using blender in edit mode.

Comment: You want to hide a face only if all its vertices are in the vertex group ?

Comment: yes, I want to hide faces that have vertex that is in vertex group

Comment: Did you try the mask modifier ?

Comment: I want to hide it in edit mode using python, behaving in a way similar to pressing H to hide part of the meshes